# Connecting Azure VM to domain with Azure AD DS - Event ID: 4097 "The user name or password is incorrect."

Tags: domain, virtual-machines, entra-id, entra-domain-services

When trying to connect an Azure VM to Azure AD DS, I get the message below, even though I have logged in successfully with the username/password elsewhere, and the account used to connect to the domain is a member of "AAD DC Administrators":

> "The user name or password is incorrect."

In Event Viewer under "Windows Log > System" I get the corresponding error message:

`"The machine ***** attempted to join the domain *******.onmicrosoft.com but failed. The error code was 1326."` (VM and domain removed)

```
Event ID: 4097
NetStatusCode: 1326
```

**Note:** When I do an nslookup for *******.onmicrosoft.com on the Azure VM it is able to resolve the DNS.

Any suggestions on what I need to do to join the domain?

Comment: Hmmm...Weird. I just tried exactly the same steps again and it worked this time. Is there some type of time delay after Azure AD users are created before their permissions take effect?

Comment: There is typically a lag regarding object creation in Azure and availability of the object.  It seems you experienced this.  Much the same as creating a mailbox in O365......wait.....wait....2 hours later....hey, it's there.  Happy New Year.

Answer (score 0):

The error code 1326 corresponds to bad credentials. Check this link and section,.
[Table   10.7 Failure to connect to a domain controller Error Codes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961817.aspx)

From your computer verify the credentials with:

> net use \\dcname\ipc$ /u:< domain\user > < password >

Comment: Yes, except I used the exact same credentials the second time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to take some time for changes in Azure AD to take effect. I tried connecting to the domain with a newly created Azure account. After waiting a while, I tried the same username and password again and it worked. I also noticed that it took a while for a newly created group on the Azure AD to be available on the Azure VM (after the Azure VM had been successfully added to the domain).